# On mouse over shows up Flash animation in different place

Tags: javascript, flash, onmouseover

I have an image on website which is my button, and I want to create mouseover effect- when you are over the image, flash animation shows up in certain place on the website. Ive browsed other topics, tried answers, but I cant hide flash animation before its called from mouseover effect. I want it to be unseen, until mouseover effect on image, and disappear when mouseover effect is gone.

Id be greatful for any help.

Regards,

Mike

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: You're using "javascript" and "flash" as your tags...do you mean you have a regular web page that needs to show a div with flash??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should set your animation's visibility to false. Then add eventListeners:

```
button.AddEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
button.AddEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
```

Then event handlers:

```
function onMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
    animation.Visible = true;
}

function onMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
    animation.Visible = false;
}
```